Understanding MPU6050 raw values in 2 complement form
I am working with an MPU6050 and STM32F103. While reading the datasheet I see that the Accelerometer and Gyro values are stored in registered in 2 complements form.

Datasheet Link: https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf
But all the examples I have seen on youtube or read somewhere never make any calculation for the 2 complements staff. Everywhere I see that the values are simply calculated as
uint16 x = HIGH_BYTE << 8 | LOW_BYTE
How this even can produce a negative value?

2-complement 16-bit signed int precisely fits some 16-bit unsinged int. So, if you get high and low byte (of 2-complement 16-bit signed value !), combine it into some uint16, and then "rename" it like int16_t x_signed = (int16_t) x_insigned - you get a right value. (And if you write something like int32_t z_signed = (int32_t) x_insigned - the value would be wrong for negative numbers)

I made a mistake there.. basically the casting (to signed 16 bit), takes account the 15 bits only, and the MSB is used for signing purpose. thats what 16 bit signed max value is 32767, which is basically all 15 bits as 1  (111111111111111)

On a quick search found MPU6050BasicExample.ino on a github project. In that code you can see the values being read and then cast as 16-bit signed values (int16_t):
void readAccelData(int16_t * destination)
{
  uint8_t rawData[6];  // x/y/z accel register data stored here
  readBytes(MPU6050_ADDRESS, ACCEL_XOUT_H, 6, &rawData[0]);  // Read the six raw data registers into data array
  destination[0] = (int16_t)((rawData[0] << 8) | rawData[1]) ;  // Turn the MSB and LSB into a signed 16-bit value
  destination[1] = (int16_t)((rawData[2] << 8) | rawData[3]) ;  
  destination[2] = (int16_t)((rawData[4] << 8) | rawData[5]) ; 
}

void readGyroData(int16_t * destination)
{
  uint8_t rawData[6];  // x/y/z gyro register data stored here
  readBytes(MPU6050_ADDRESS, GYRO_XOUT_H, 6, &rawData[0]);  // Read the six raw data registers sequentially into data array
  destination[0] = (int16_t)((rawData[0] << 8) | rawData[1]) ;  // Turn the MSB and LSB into a signed 16-bit value
  destination[1] = (int16_t)((rawData[2] << 8) | rawData[3]) ;  
  destination[2] = (int16_t)((rawData[4] << 8) | rawData[5]) ; 
}

I haven't attempted to run it, but the above code looks OK to me in terms of how to interpret the MPU6050 register contents as signed 16-bit values.
